# Why is my cake sinking after baking with a soggy-like line in the middle?

Tags: baking, cake, dough, texture

I've lately been facing an issue with my cakes whereby they sink and have a soggy-like line near the bottom.
It's strange since I am using the same ingredients, same oven, same recipe however the cakes are turning out like this..

[image: Soggy line]

It's quite frustrating since these are commercial cakes and I can't sell such cakes to customers.

Comment: Have you checked the oven temperature with a thermometer?

Comment: Are you using the same baking ban as well? Maybe a bad batch of an ingredient, under the assumption you buy large quantities, as you said these are commercial cakes.

Comment: You said same oven & recipe, but did anything else change?  Like the size of the pan, material and/or thickness of the pan, or the number of pans being baked at the same time?  And it's worth getting a thermometer in there -- although it's rare, sensors, electronics, and/or heating elements can fail over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those cakes are underbaked, that line at the bottom is a clear sign that the batter hadn't crystallized when it was removed from the oven, so it could not support the cake above. There's a few things that could be happening:

- You changed the recipe or ingredients: if you've made a substitution or changed the recipe you should look at changing it back
- You aren't baking them long enough: changes in the starting temperature of the batter can change the baking time. In the winter your kitchen may be colder so your batter may be colder, or maybe you're pulling ingredients straight from the fridge, if your batter is colder than you need to lengthen the baking time
- Your oven is cooler: it's possible your oven thermostat is mis-reading and your oven is cooler, or maybe you're cramming the oven with many cakes and your oven can't keep to temperature. Also, maybe you're opening the oven door lots and losing heat. Try using an oven thermometer to check the temperature

I would suggest you start testing your cakes for doneness before taking them out, it's not uncommon for ovens to fluctuate so you can't assume that a cake is going to be done at an exact time. Use the poke test and/or an instant read thermometer to check them.

Comment: Too much leavener could cause an over-rise and collapse, causing that gummy, under-baked layer as well. A substitution or brand change on that front could be a culprit.

Comment: @AMtwo IIRC not adding enough leavener can also cause similar sorts of consistencies, as well. No air bubbles, no crumb, and you just get a slimy mess rather than a proper cake.

Comment: @GdD  Wow, thank you for a very comprehensive answer, I'll look into each of these suggestions and act on them. But I firmly believe the oven has become faulty over time. The oven door doesn't close well. Probably cold air is seeping in